# Having issues printing out a calendar (both yearlong and month long) based on a date the user enters. Plus trouble with calculating Zellers Congruence

Tags: c, function, pointers, math, calendar

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printCalendarMonth();
void printCalendarYear();
int zellersCongruence();
void personalizedCalendar();
void firstCalendarMonth();
void perpetual();
void lunarPhase(); // declaring functions

enum month {
  January = 1,
  February,
  March,
  April,
  May,
  June,
  July,
  August,
  September,
  October,
  November,
  December // assigning a number with each month
};

int main() {
  int month[] = {};
  int z;
  int x;
  int y;
  int d;
  //The daycode of the first day of each month
  int daycode;
  enum month m; // declaring month day year and choice variables
  printf("\nEnter 1 to use a personalized calendar");
  printf("\nEnter 2 to print a past calendar or date");
  printf("\n\nEnter here: ");
  scanf("%i",
        &z); // select 1 for personalized calendar and 2 for everything else
  if (z == 1) {
    
    return (0);
  } else if (z == 2) {
    do {
      printf("Enter a year: ");
      scanf("%d", &y);
      if (y < 1582) {
        y = 0;
        printf("Year cannot be less than 1582!\n");
      }
    } while (y == 0); // asks for year and checks value

    if (y > 1582) { // if year is greater than 1582
      do {
        printf("\nSelect a month (1-12) of the year %i: ", y);
        scanf("%i", &m);
        switch (m) {
        case January:
          m = 1;
          break;
        case February:
          m = 2;
          break;
        case March:
          m = 3;
          break;
        case April:
          m = 4;
          break;
        case May:
          m = 5;
          break;
        case June:
          m = 6;
          break;
        case July:
          m = 7;
          break;
        case August:
          m = 8;
          break;
        case September:
          m = 9;
          break;
        case October:
          m = 10;
          break;
        case November:
          m = 11;
          break;
        case December:
          m = 12;
          break;
        default:
          printf("\nInvalid Month\n");
          m = 0;
        }
      } while (m == 0);
    } else if (y == 1582) { // if year entered is 1582
      do {
        printf("\nSelect a month (10-12) of the year 1582: ");
        scanf("%i", &m);
        switch (m) {
        case October:
          m = 10;
          break;
        case November:
          m = 11;
          break;
        case December:
          m = 12;
          break;
        default:
          printf("\nInvalid Month\n");
          m = 0;
        }
      } while (m == 0); // there are only 3 months on the gregorian calendar in
                        // the year 1582
    }
  }
  do {
    printf("Select a day in %d/%d: ", m, y);
    scanf("%i", &d);
    if (y == 1582 && m == 10 && (d >= 5 && d <= 14)) { // checks if day entered for october of 1582 is correct
      d = 0;
      printf("October 5th through 14th do not exist in October of 1852");
    } else if ((m == 1 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 7 || m == 8 || m == 10 || m == 12) && (d < 1 || d > 31)) { // checks months with 31 days
      d = 0;
      printf(
          "\nYour month has between 1 and 31 days.\nSelect a different day: ");
    } else if ((m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11) && (d < 1 || d > 30)) { // checks months with 30 days
      d = 0;
      printf(
          "\nYour month has between 1 and 30 days.\nSelect a different day: ");
    } else if (m == 2 && ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || y % 400 == 0) && (d < 1 || d > 29)) { // checks February on a leap year
      d = 0;
      printf("\nThis february is a leap year and thus has between 1 and 29 "
             "days.\nSelect a different day: ");
    } else if (m == 2 && (d < 1 || d > 28)) { // checks February on a non leap year
      d = 0;
      printf("\nThis february is not a leap year so it has between 1 and 28 "
             "days.\nSelect a different day: ");
    } else { // no other exceptions so date must b correct
      printf("\nThe date you've selected is: %d/%d/%d", m, d, y);
    }
  } while (d == 0);
  printf("\n\nWhat would you like to do with this date?");
  printf("\nEnter 1 to print the month calendar");
  printf("\nEnter 2 to print the year calendar");
  printf("\nEnter 3 to discover what day of the week %d/%d/%d is", m, d, y);
  printf("\nEnter 4 to discover what moon phase occured the day of %d/%d/%d", m,
         d, y); // menu options for date user has given
  do {
    printf("\n\nEnter choice here: ");
    scanf("%i", &z); // scans users choice
    switch (z) {
    case 1:
      printCalendarYear(); // calls print calendar year function
      break;
    case 2:
      printCalendarMonth(); // calls print calendar month function
      break;
    case 3:
      daycode = zellersCongruence(m, d, y); // calls zellers congruence function and uses variables given
      char day[10];
      switch (daycode) {
      case 0:
        strcpy(day, "Sunday");
        break;
      case 1:
        strcpy(day, "Monday");
        break;
      case 2:
        strcpy(day, "Tuesday");
        break;
      case 3:
        strcpy(day, "Wednesday");
        break;
      case 4:
        strcpy(day, "Thursday");
        break;
      case 5:
        strcpy(day, "Friday");
        break;
      case 6:
        strcpy(day, "Saturday");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Zeller's switch has failed!");
        break;
      }
      printf("The date you entered %d/%d/%d is a %s!", d, m, y, day);
      break;
    case 4:
      lunarPhase(); // calls lunar phase function
      break;
    default:
      z = 0;
      printf("Invalid choice made."); // must enter one of the choices above
    }
  } while (z == 0);
}

void printCalendarMonth(int mon[]) {
  printf(" Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri   Sat");
  // Fist Week in which the Month starts
  printf("\n| %2d |", mon[0]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[1]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[2]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[3]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[4]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[5]);
  printf(" %2d |\n", mon[6]);
  printf("| %2d |", mon[7]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[8]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[9]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[10]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[11]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[12]);
  printf(" %2d |\n", mon[13]);
  printf("| %2d |", mon[14]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[15]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[16]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[17]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[18]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[19]);
  printf(" %2d |\n", mon[20]);
  printf("| %2d |", mon[21]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[22]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[23]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[24]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[25]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[26]);
  printf(" %2d |\n", mon[27]);
  printf("| %2d |", mon[28]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[29]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[30]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[31]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[32]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[33]);
  printf(" %2d |\n", mon[34]);
  printf("| %2d |", mon[35]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[36]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[37]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[38]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[39]);
  printf(" %2d |", mon[40]);
  printf(" %2d |\n", mon[41]);
}

// Function that create the arrays that will be used to print the individual
// months
void perpetual(int daycode) {
  int blank = 0;
  int i, k, m = 0;
  int month[] = {};
  do {
    month[i] = blank;
    ++i;
  } while (i < daycode);

  do {
    month[i + k] = k;
    ++k;
  } while (k < 31);
  month[i + k] = k;

  do {
    month[k + m] = blank;
    ++m;
  } while (m < 41);
}

// Funtion to call and print the frist month of the gregorian Calender: Oct,
// 1582
void firstCalendarMonth() {
  int Julian_Oct[] = {0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  15, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
                      22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0,  0,  0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0};
  printCalendarMonth(Julian_Oct);
}

void printCalendarYear(int year) {
  int i = 1;
  int h;
  int month[] = {};
  do {
    perpetual(zellersCongruence(1, i, year));
    printCalendarYear(month);
    ++i;
  } while (i <= 12);
}

void lunarPhase() {
  // References the user's inputs ofr month, year, day
  int m;
  int y;
  int d;
  // Initialzing variables that the function will use
  float julian_date;
  float days_since_new_moon;
  float phase;
  // Converting the int to float vaiables
  float day = d;
  float year = y;
  float month = m;
  if (m < 3) {
    year--;
    month += 12;
  }
  // Calculate the Julian date
  julian_date =
      floor(365.25 * year) + floor(30.59 * (month - 2)) + day + 1721088.5;

  // Calculate the number of days since the last new moon
  days_since_new_moon = julian_date - 2451549.5;

  // Calculate the current phase of the moon
  phase = fmod((days_since_new_moon / 29.53), 1.0);

  // Determine the phase of the moon
  if (phase < 0.03 || phase > 0.97) {
    printf("The moon is in the new moon phase\n");
  } else if (phase < 0.23) {
    printf("The moon is in the waxing crescent phase\n");
  } else if (phase < 0.27) {
    printf("The moon is in the first quarter phase\n");
  } else if (phase < 0.48) {
    printf("The moon is in the waxing gibbous phase\n");
  } else if (phase < 0.52) {
    printf("The moon is in the full moon phase\n");
  } else if (phase < 0.73) {
    printf("The moon is in the waning gibbous phase\n");
  } else if (phase < 0.77) {
    printf("The moon is in the last quarter phase\n");
  } else {
    printf("The moon is in the waning crescent phase\n");
  };
}

int zellersCongruence(int d, int m, int y) {
  int x;
  int k;
  int j;
  int h;
  if (m == 1) {
    m = 13;
    y--;
  }
  if (m == 2) {
    m = 14;
    y--;
  }
  x = (13 * (m + 1));
  h = d + (x / 5) + k + (k / 4) + (j / 4) - (2 * j);
  h = h % 7;
  return (h);
}
```

For Zeller's congruence, it calculated 5/8/2023 as a Sunday when it's supposed to be a Monday. Trying to print out the calendar results in an error "signal segmentation fault (core dumped)". Although Zeller's Congruence isn't correct we still tried to print out a calendar based on the incorrect starting point. Zellers was a void function but we've been trying to re work the program so its since been changed.

Comment: `int month[] = {};` ===> What do you think this does?

Comment: This code has a large number of warnings and errors. If you are not seeing the warnings you need to adjust your compiler settings, and you need to pay attention to them. Since you did not specify the input you are using I guessed and the crash is because you pass no argument to a function that expects one. https://godbolt.org/z/aYqboqTTc My advice would be to start with a small skeleton program and add each function one at a time and test them, then put the rest of the logic together.

Comment: To be more specific, `printCalendarMonth()` expects an `int array[]`, but you didn't pass an argument to it.

Comment: The day of the week calculation likely fails because two of the variables `j` and `k` in the formula are uninitialized.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added k = y % 100 and j = y / 100 but still not working. I already have int j and int k but i must've forgotten that bit when I was reworking it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja looks identical, I even swapped it for the rosetta stone and it gave me Sunday. (5/8/2023 was Monday)

Comment: @RetiredNinja I copy and pasted your code but it doesn't work properly for all dates. I was experiencing this same issue earlier as well. While it does yesterday correctly, it thinks this Thursday the 11th is actually a Tuesday.

Comment: @Haris its initializing an array month but its to be used as a placeholder.

Comment: There's a weird `switch` statement that is close to pointless.  It starts: `switch (m){ case January: m = 1; break;` — if the value in `m` is `1` (aka `January`), set `m` to `1`; rinse and repeat for the other months; only the `default:` case does anything useful.  Use `if (m < January || m > December) { printf("\nInvalid Month\n"); m = 0; }` to validate the month instead of 40 lines or so of code.

Comment: In `zellersCongruence()`, you don't set `j` before you use it — that is not a recipe for happiness.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).